# Function that return TRUE with a given probability

Tags: r, probability

I'm looking for a function that returns `TRUE` with a given probability. Something like:

```
> proba = 2/3
> function(proba)
```

It returns `TRUE` (or 1) with a probability of 2/3 and it returns `FALSE` (or 0) with a probability of 1/3

The only way to compute that I can think of is:

```
> sample(c(rep(1,ceiling(proba*100)),rep(0,ceiling((1-proba)*100))),1)
```

but it gives only an approximation (and it is not really good looking !) as it can only deal with values that have a finite number of decimals.

Comment: "can only deal with values that have a finite number of decimals" - yeah, but do you really need INFINITE precision? You'll never have it.

Comment: Otherwise, this is a binomial distribution: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Binomial.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
proba <- 2/3   
# number of values:
n <- 1

as.logical(rbinom(n,size=1,prob=proba))
```

Answer (score 3):

`prob <- runif(1)>0.3333333`  will do it for you. Or in the general case,

```
prob <-function(winval) runif(1)>(1-winval)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
function(proba) sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, prob = c(proba, 1 - proba))
```

And if you want to be able to draw any number of TRUE/FALSE, not just one:

```
function(proba, size) sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size, prob = c(proba, 1 - proba),
                             replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, you can avoid the doubt about the fractional representation of your probabilities by creating the total population and then performing a selection, like so:

```
sample(c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 1)), 1)
```

OR

```
sample(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

Usually, we use probabilities to represent the selection likelihood of a population of unknown or feasibly uncountable size.  Probability is used as a proxy.  When you know the details of the population, using the exact population is actually preferred from a mathematical perspective.  It also has the side-effect of being a more accurate representation of this specific problem.

To extend the solution, you would need to convert your probabilities into a population total for each population subset.  In this case, we have two subsets: TRUE, and FALSE.  Instead of representing the selection likelihood of a TRUE individual as 2/3, you would instead state the number of TRUE individuals contained in the total population TRUE_N, and the number of FALSE individuals contained in the total population FALSE_N.

```
TRUE_N <- 2
FALSE_N <- 1
sample(c(rep(TRUE, TRUE_N), rep(FALSE, FALSE_N)), 1)
```